# Why isn't component-did-mount working reagent?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have the following:

```
(def load-map (with-meta identity {:component-did-mount e/load-map}))

(defn my-component []
    [load-map
   [:div {:id "map"}]
   ]

)
```

where e/load-map is:

```
(defn load-map []
    (loadMap)
)
```

where the loadMap function is imported from a js file:

```
export function loadMap() {
    console.log("creating script tag on dom");
    // Create the script tag, set the appropriate attributes
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDoJwW4_MfQzY&callback=initMap';
    script.defer = true;
    script.async = true;

    // Attach your callback function to the `window` object
    window.initMap = function() {
        console.log("init map");
        console.log("Element is ", document.getElementById("map") )
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });
    };

    // Append the 'script' element to 'head'
    document.head.appendChild(script);

}
```

The console logs print, but the map doesn't show. On the other hand, putting a `<div id="map"></div>` in index.html and triggering the e/load-map event on page load using the following reitit route

```
["/"
     {:name        :my-component
      :view        #'my-component
      :controllers [{:start e/load-map}]}]
```

works.

Comment: I think the title has more negatives than you intend, unless you meant to ask why the code given in the question works (when, presumably, it's expected to be broken).

Answer (score 0):

### Prerequisites

Referencing [Reagent documentation](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0-alpha2/doc/tutorials/creating-reagent-components#the-core-of-a-component) we can see that:

> A `render` function is the backbone, mandatory part of a component

This is the exact thing your `load-map` component lacks and the reason it won't render anything.

Looking at the same documentation, we can see that the agreed upon nomeclature specifies [three main ways](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0-alpha2/doc/tutorials/creating-reagent-components#the-three-ways) of defining a component in `Reagent`:

1. [Form 1](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0-alpha2/doc/tutorials/creating-reagent-components#form-1-a-simple-function): returning a simple Hiccup vector.
2. [Form 2](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0-alpha2/doc/tutorials/creating-reagent-components#form-2--a-function-returning-a-function): returning a function that returns a Hiccup vector.
3. [Form 3](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0-alpha2/doc/tutorials/creating-reagent-components#form-3-a-class-with-life-cycle-methods): returning a *class* with life cycle methods.

### Code

While `my-component` uses the `Form 1` style, `load-map` is a `Form 3` component. Therefore, `load-map` should return a *class* and a `:reagent-render` key.

The result would be something like this:

```
(defn my-component []
      (reagent.core/create-class
        {:component-did-mount
          e/load-map
         :reagent-render
          (fn []
             [:div {:id "map"}])}))
```

Notice the combination of the two components. There is no functional need for them to be separate.
Though if you absolutely have to have them separately, add the same class definition for `load-map` component, and on `:reagent-render` key have a dummy `(fn [] [:<>])` ([Reagent version](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0-alpha2/doc/tutorials/react-features) of [React fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)).